# Pegar os campos de um Select e passar para viewmodel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, array, html-helpers

Galera possuo dois ***Selects Multiple*** onde a função deles é trocar valores conforme na imagem abaixo:

[image: Selects]

O primeiro na real é um ***DropDownList*** onde ele busca as informações do banco, segue o seu codigo:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Avaible", ViewBag.Account as SelectList, new { multiple = "multiple", id = "Avaliable", name = "Avaliable" })
```

O outro é um ***Select*** que recebe esses valores, segue o seu codigo:

```
 <select style="width:70px" id="Included" name="Included" multiple></select>
```

Os dois botões fazem a transição de dados de um pro outro por meio de JavaScript:

```
function Incluir() {
    $("#Included").append($("#Avaliable option:selected"));
}
```

E então ele popula o select que recebe os valores, o problema é, preciso pegar esses valores e armazenar em uma variavel da ViewModel Chamada Accounts

```
  public List<int> Accounts { get; set; }
```

Tentei fazer metodo em JavaScript que retorna todos os valores do Select, porém não consigo armazenar isso na variavel Accounts, esta é a função que fiz:

```
function displayResult() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Included");
    var array = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        array[i] = x.options[i].value;
    }
    alert(array);
    $('#Accounts').push(array);
}
```

Porém ele não consegue popular o Accounts, alguem poderia me ajudar como popular essa Lista Accounts com os valores do Select ? Se tiver algum método melhor ou ajudar pra transferir o Array para o Accounts. 
Ah esqueci de falar, na View possui um campo referenciando o Accounts:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Accounts)
```

Comment: Então, o problema é que na hora de pegar essa Lista e jogar pra Controller popular o Accounts(que esta na viewModel), ele não manda os valores

Comment: Uma alternativa é você renomear select "Included"  para o "Accounts" e antes do submit selecionar todos as options dele.

Comment: Cara Deu certo, Valeu @LeandroAngelo !!

Comment: só não esqueça de fazer a seleção de todos os itens antes do submit, se o usuário desmarcar eles não vão chegar para você na controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa armazenar a seleção em um input hidden "Accounts" isso inclusive pode ser feito mas você precisará alterar a sua model e adicionar novos tratamentos no backend para processar a entrada

Como sugerido nos comentários, uma solução, é você renomear o seu segundo select com o `name="Accounts[]"` e garantir que todos os seus itens estejão selecionados antes de fazer o submit para a sua controller.

```js
function Incluir() {
  $("#Accounts").append($("#Avaliable option:selected"));
}

function displayResult() {
  //Essa linha de código vai selecionar todos os itens que existem
  //no select #Accounts para garantir a sua persistência à Controller
  $("#Accounts option").prop('selected', true);


  console.log($("#Accounts").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select style="width:70px" id="Avaliable" name="Avaliable" multiple>
  <option value="123">123</option>
  <option value="321">321</option>
  <option value="111">111</option>
  <option value="222">222</option>
  <option value="333">333</option>
</select>
<button id="Adicionar" onclick="Incluir()">></button>
<select style="width:70px" id="Accounts" name="Accounts[]" multiple></select>
<br>
<button onclick="displayResult()">Enviar</button>
```